# iPhone 4 is stuck in a boot loop, has a broken power button -- how do I put it in DFU mode?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4 that has a broken power button. There is no warranty because I bought it from my friend.

It has never been a problem because I had AssistiveTouch, until now.

I went to use the iPhone one day and it was stuck in a boot loop.

I have never attempted to jailbreak it or install 3rd party software onto it. When I connect it to iTunes it says that I need to respond on the iPhone before I can restore or sync it. I can't respond because it's in a boot loop and I can't enter DFU mode because the power button is broken.

Is there a way to put the phone in to DFU mode when it's power button is broken?

UPDATE: After I made this post, I plugged my iPhone into a Samsung wall charger and it booted properly. I used it all day, until it died. Once I got home, I plugged it into the charger, and now it's stuck on the boot loop again. When the iPhone booted normally, iTunes allowed me to put files on it, etc. I have already tried RecBoot, and iTunes won't let me sync.

Comment: Do you really need hardware DFU mode or just normal recovery mode?

Comment: Have you managed to fix it? I have the same problem with my ipad

Comment: maybe if the software on your phone is acting as not expected and also the hardware is defect it's time to think about a new phone ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is stuck in recovery mode, DO THIS: (ON Screen USB pointing to a CD with a Music Note).

1. Make sure your iTunes is up to data, if not re-download itunes.
2. after re-installing ITUNES, plug your iphone via USB into your computer. ITUNES will automatically pick it up and a pop up box will probally say that your IPHONE is in recovery mode would you like to restore?
3. Click the restore tab.
   Note - If ITUNES if out of date, this will not work.
   Note - Do not do this over WIFI
   Note - Do not interrupt the restore
   Note - If you did not make a previous back up, your IPHONE will restore back to the factroy settings.

All this happened to me, fortunately I made a back up. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to have iTunes recognize the phone and are able to attempt to do a restore, you can use [redsn0w](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/) to modify a download of the current iOS firmware version (the version you have on the phone) to create a new firmware file whose purpose is just to boot up the phone in DFU mode (without the having to use the power/sleep and home buttons).

The entire process is described in this tutorial by iClarified - [How to Enter DFU Mode With a Broken Home or Power Button](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=23009) (it's for Windows, but it's the same process on OS X).

- Download the latest version of [redsn0w](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=16424) for your OS (OS X or Windows)
- Download the right firmware for your current iOS version for the iPhone 4 from Apple through the [direct links on this iOS firmware download page](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750)
- Extract the redsn0w zip file and run the redsn0w application
- Click the **Extras** button in the main window
- Click the **Even More** button in the Extras window
- Click **DFU IPSW**
- Acknowledge the dialog that describes that this is for devices with broken buttons
- Choose the firmware file you downloaded earlier from Apple
- redsn0w will let you know once it's done creating a new firmware file for DFU mode (the name would start with ENTER_DFU)
- Connect your device with iTunes open and in the *Summary* view, click **Restore** while holding <kbd>Option</kbd> (on OS X) or <kbd>Shift</kbd> (on Windows)
- When iTunes prompts you to choose the firmware, select the ENTER_DFU firmware file
- Once the device is restored, it will be in DFU mode

Comment: Since this restores the device, it will wipe all data, right?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Recboot. This will often let you put the phone in recovery mode. here is the link http://sebby.net/recboot-mac/recboot_2_2.zip